# Komma in "und wenig später" beim letzten Glied einer Aufzählung

Tags: comma

Betrachten wir den folgenden Satz:

> In der zweiten Hälfte der 60er-Jahre entstanden Programmiersprachen wie etwa ALGOL W, Simula 67, ALGOL 68, PL/1(,) und(,) wenig später, bereits stark beeinflusst durch das gewachsene Verständnis für das Gebiet der strukturierten Programmierung, die Sprachen C und Pascal.

Kommt ein Komma vor und nach "und"? Warum oder warum nicht?

Answer (score 2):

Hinter das *und* gehört ganz sicher kein Komma. Ohne den Einschub *, bereits … Programmierung,* lautet der Teilsatz wie folgend:

> … und wenig später die Sprachen C und Pascal.

*Wenig später* ist ein Zwilling der adverbialen Bestimmung *In der zweiten Hälfte der 60er-Jahre* am Anfang des Satzes. Die interessantere Frage ist, ob **vor** das *und* ein Komma gehört. Dazu ein einfacheres Beispiel:

> Erst fiel der Groschen und dann das Papiergeld.

Da der zweite Teilsatz ab dem *und* kein eigenes Verb enthält braucht man kein Komma. Es handelt sich dann um eine Aufzählung von adverbial bestimmten Objekten. Man kann ein Komma setzen, dann muss man sich das zweite *fiel* als Ellipse dazudenken und der Satz ähnelt dem folgenden:

> Erst fiel der Groschen, (und) dann fielen die Scheine.

Hier sind es zwei verkettete Hauptsätze und das Komma ist zwingend.

Comment: Nein. Grammatisch geht es nur darum, ob ein weiteres Verb vorliegt oder nicht. Mit einer Ellipse kann man viele "ungrammatische" Konstruktionen erklären, wirklich stimmig ist diese Erklärung aber eigentlich nur dann, wenn der ausgelassene Teil eine wörtliche Wiederholung wäre.

Comment: In deinem Beispiel **kann** man ein Komma vor das *und* setzen, muss es aber nicht tun. Ich würde darauf verzichten, weil die Aufzählung ja mit Pascal und C weitergeht.

Answer (score 0):

Dieses sogenannte "Oxford comma" gibt es im Deutschen nicht. Im Englischen herrscht allerdings eine langanhaltende Debatte darüber, ob man es setzen soll oder nicht. Bei der derzeitigen starken Beeinflussung durch das Englische ist es daher nicht unwahrscheinlich, dass diese Ausdrucksweise auch im Deutschen Einzug halten wird und wir hier die ersten Vorboten davon sehen.